# Oracle user DB export command's scope (User/Schema level)?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm totally novice in terms of Oracle DB knowledge. Trying to understand IMPDB command and its scope.

Issue: Suppose there are 500 tables in a particular DB, many of them (60% - 70% or more) are coming as zero records when we're importing the data into a fresh Oracle DB (getting the data from one vendor who has the DB). The doubt is, how can most of the tables be zero records in a DB (why were they created at the first place then?). Also, we're assuming maybe the vendor is using a specific user while generating the .DMP files who has no access to those tables and hence the 0 count. When we asked the vendor, they said, that's not how Oracle works, they've provided user export dump and said, "Schema is a collection of database objects owned by a specific user. Those objects include tables, indexes, views, functions, stored procedures, etc."

When asked about the zero records issue, they said they're pulling correctly and have no understanding as to why so many tables are zero. The SO community has great experts in Oracle DB, can anyone shed some light as to:

1. What might be the issue?
2. Is our assumption correct (i.e, that user doesn't have access to those tables which got zero records)?
3. What's the right way forward?

4) Anything else you want to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vendor is correct - the utility used to generate the export, `EXPDP` (the compliment to `IMPDP`) can create a full dump of all of the database objects of a specific user. However, the parameters used to generate the export can vary greatly, and it's absolutely possible for an export to not include table data **IF** the `EXPDP` command/parameters used to create the export are specified in that way. For example, let's imagine that someone wants to export a specific schema using the following commmand:

```
expdp [USER]@[DATABASE] schemas=test directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=test.dmp logfile=test.log query=TEST.TABLE:'"WHERE row_date>sysdate"'
```

While the export is being generated, all of the rows in that specific table will be evaluated based on the where condition. Unless rows have a date that is in the future, none of the rows dated prior and up to the sysdate will be exported. If a where condition like that is applied to the entire export, you'll have tables with 0 rows in the dump file.

That is just an example - it might also be the case that the tables really have 0 rows. This is possible for a lot of reasons - perhaps it is an older schema with tables that have previously been truncated. Perhaps that particular database isn't used often, and the tables within the schema are empty because rows were never added to the tables. Maybe a developer or another DBA created a bunch of unnecessary tables and they simply were never dropped. It could be a plethora of potential reasons/issues for a schema to have empty tables, and that doesn't mean there is something wrong with the database or the export file being generated. Applications and their technical requirements change all the time, and it's possible that the schema simply wasn't updated when those tables were no longer needed.

The first thing I would recommend is:

1. Ask the vendor to provide record counts of each table in that schema from their end for validation purposes. This will tell you if the tables are empty in the database. If they are empty in the database, they will be empty in your export. This is very simple and can be achieved with a query like `select owner, table_name, num_rows, sample_size, last_analyzed from all_tables where owner=[SCHEMA];` provided that their table statistics are up to date.

If this is a big concern for you, you can always ask them to exclude those tables in the export with a command like:

`expdp [USER]@[DATABASE] schemas=test exclude=TABLE:"IN ('Table1', 'Table2')" directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=test.dmp logfile=test.log`

Or simply exclude them during your import with a command like:

`impdp [USER]@[DATABASE] schemas=test exclude=TABLE:"IN ('Table1', 'Table2')" directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=test.dmp logfile=test.log`

Either way should work, but be careful and ensure that there will be no issues from a constraint/child record perspective. You can also exclude the constraints. There are many ways to work around it.

**IF THERE ARE INCONSISTENCIES BETWEEN THE COUNTS AND THE ROWS IMPORTED**, I would recommend asking the vendor for the specific `EXPDP` command or parameter file that was used to generate the export. This will let you know if the empty rows are being caused by a clause in the export command.

2. It's impossible to know if your assumption is correct without knowing more about the database the export is coming from or seeing the the commands being used to generate the export. I would ask the vendor to verify record counts before assuming that it's a permission issue. Empty tables are created all the time.

Comment: Should the query in point 1 be done at an admin level? I know I'm repeating my (wrong) understand (maybe). But had too, as https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/accessre.htm#i1006310 this document says it is possible to grant table level access to users. So, what if the user they're using to export are not granted with permission to select. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The clauses are done by the user that performs the export. It's possible, but in my experience DBAs are typically creating data pump exports, and they usually have privileges to select from any table unless there is data masking involved, especially in the case of sensitive financial or medical data. Either way, getting the count information for each table will tell you for sure. If the counts don't match up, then explore possible privilege issues.